# Capybara specs failing on different servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I've recently moved mi CI server (Teamcity) to another powerful machine with same configuration and pretty similar OS.

Since then some of my integration specs have started to fail. My setup is pretty standard, Rails 3 + capybara + poltergeist + phantomjs.

Failures are deterministic, they always happen and they are always related to some missing nodes in the DOM. Also, failures happens across different projects with similar setup so it's not something related to project configuration. This is happening with both capybara 1.x and capybara 2.

This is the simplest failing spec. Note that this spec runs with no need of javascript, so the issue is also present in rack only specs.

```
scenario 'require an unsubscription' do
  visit unsubscribe_index_path
  within main_content do
    choose list.description
    fill_in 'Email', :with => subscriber.email
    click_button 'Unsubscribe'
  end
  save_page # <--- Added to debug output
  # !!! HERE is the first failing assertion
  page.should have_content('You should have received a confirmation message')
  # Analytics event recorded
  # !!! this also is failing
  page.should have_event('Unsubscription', 'Sent', list_name)
  # If I comment previous two lines the spec passes on CI machine
  # this means that the form is submitted with success since email is triggered
  # from controller code
  last_email_sent.should have_subject 'Unsubscribe request received'
  last_email_sent.should deliver_to subscriber.email
end
```

What I've tried:

- run the specs on different machines, they works on every dev machine and also in a staging server. I can only reproduce the failure on the CI machine even outside of CI environment (i.e. by running the specs via command line)
- Increased `Capybara.default_wait_time` to a ridiculous `20`
- Tried with a brutal sleep before the `page.should have_content` line
- upgrade RVM, ruby, capybara, poltergeist on their latest versions on the CI machine.
- upgrade teamcity to its latest version

The strangest thing I found is when I've added a `save_page` call just before the failing line. If i run the spec on my machine and then on the CI where the server is failing and comparing those two files the result is this:

```
$ diff capybara-201309071*.html
26a27,29
> <script type='text/javascript'>
> _gaq.push(["_trackEvent","Unsubscription","Sent","listname"]);
> </script>
90a94,96
>             <div class="alert-message message notice">
>               <p>You should have received a confirmation message</p>
>             </div>
```

Which are the two missing pieces which make the spec failing, so the form is submitted, controller action is run successfully but there are two missing pieces of dom. How that is possible? And why this is happening only on one machine?

For the records, those two pieces of DOM are added with standard rails tools one with

```
redirect_to unsubscribe_index_path, notice: ...
```

and the other with the [analytical](https://github.com/jkrall/analytical) gem

Comment: Can it be possible that Unsubscribe button hasn't been clicked? I advice you to try to put a sleep before `click_button`

Comment: I experience the same issue with a couple of links/buttons in app that I test but I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, the two failing projects I'm using dalli_store as session store and I've put the `config.cache_store = :dalli_store` line in `config/application.rb` instead of `config/environments/production.rb`.

On the old CI server there was a memcached daemon running hence all specs was running fine.

In the new server since it's just a CI server and it doesn't run any production or staging code memcached is not present thus any session write (such as flash messages) was **silently** discarded and this is the reason why all that kind of specs was failing.

I solved by putting the `config.cache` line in the appropriate environment file, but I'm still wondering why dalli gem doesn't raise any warning when no memcached is available. While the choice of not failing on missing cache daemon is reasonable since the application should work with no cached data, it could be a performance killer in production code and it might go unnoticed if no warning is given.